# How click one of the button show its value

Tags: javascript

The following code show three buttons, I want click the one show its value.
I try bt[i].firstChild.nodeValue or bt[i].innerHTML all not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
window.onload=function(){
    var bt = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i=0;i<bt.length;i++){
        bt[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(bt[i].firstChild.nodeValue);      //TypeError: bt[i] is undefined
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

```
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="third">Third</button>
```

Comment: Where is your js script | before or after html code ...?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: The onclick function you are creating does is not aware of what `i` is, since it will be run when the button is clicked and the cycle will be long be finished

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this code using EventListener and loops for attaching for each button 'click' event listener:

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(let i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].addEventListener("click", getValue);
}

function getValue() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
<button id="third">Third</button>
```

end read about [JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: Don't dump code and say "Try this...". Explain what you did and why/how it works.